# Which kind of healthy vitamins and enzymes decrease during freezing?

Tags: micronutrients, food-safety, fruits, vegetable, frozen-freeze

I heard that a lot of useful vitamins, minerals and enzymes are not saved and decrease after different periods in the freezer. Is it true? How does the temperature of freezing and duration of saving in cool influence the quality of products like vegetables, fruits, and protein food?

Comment: Could you please give the source where you heard that minerals and vitamins and enzymes decrease after periods in the freezer? You may also want to see [What kind of research is expected here before asking questions?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/353/what-kind-of-research-is-expected-here-before-asking-questions) Thanks :)

Comment: For example, It is considered in this article, but there it`s not full list of food like protein food and other vegetables and fruits.